# 3G USB MODEMS NOT WORKING IN UBUNTU 13.04

Tags: usb, modem, 3g

WHAT HAPPENED TO UBUNTU THAT IT HARDLY SUPPORT ANY TYPE OF 3G USB MODEM, IT REQUIRE A LOT OF GOOGLING TO GET THE MODEM WORK.  IS THERE ANY PERMANENT SOLUTION TO THIS PROBLEM IN FUTURE RELEASES

GAURAV BHAMBRI
KUBUNTU 13.04 DELHI INDIA

Comment: You should not use capital letters when you write a question.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would tell us what 3G USB Modem you're using.  Someone out there may have mocked up a different kernel or driver that is capable of making the device work.

Answer (score 2):

AFIK the "permanent solution" is to chedk hardware compatibility lists before you buy. Many wireless usb cards list compatibility with linux on the box.

I also check the return policy before I buy. My local computer shop (the one I deal with) knows I use Linux, so they allow me to test before I buy.